# exec not found using Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

Reading up on the Dockerfile documentation for [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/shell-form-entrypoint-example), I am having an issue trying to rewrite one of my commands:

As it runs today, without issues:

```
# Startup
ENTRYPOINT ["/etc/init.d/hook", "/run/apache2/apache2.pid", "/etc/init.d/apache2 start"]
```

According to various sources, I should fork my hook process using *exec*, so I have simple changed the entrypoint to

```
ENTRYPOINT ["exec", "/etc/init.d/hook", "/run/apache2/apache2.pid", "/etc/init.d/apache2 start"]
```

But now I receive the following error:

> container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"exec\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Why can `exec` not be found? Is this not a bash builtin?

If I attach to the container, I can run exec without issue

```
$ docker exec -it $( docker ps | grep imagename | awk '{print $1}' ) bash
root@f704bfe5d6c6:/# exec echo hi
hi
```

How can I use `exec` in my `ENTRYPOINT` directive?

**edit**

Here is a Dockerfile that reproduces the error

```
FROM ubuntu:16.10
ENTRYPOINT ["exec", "echo", "hi"]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Interestingly, I can make this work by simply removing the parameters from an array

This will work as expected

```
ENTRYPOINT exec echo hi
```

While this will generate the error

```
ENTRYPOINT ["exec", "echo", "hi"]
```

Comment: That's because the first form is passed to a shell and the second is not. So `exec` is found, because it's a shell builtin. In the second form you call `exec` and without a shell to provide it, it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `ENTRYPOINT ["exec", "/etc/init.d/hook", "/run/apache2/apache2.pid", "/etc/init.d/apache2",  "start"]`

check the doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/entrypoint

should also work

`ENTRYPOINT /etc/init.d/hook /run/apache2/apache2.pid /etc/init.d/apache2 start`

Comment: Just tried, and still get the same error, `container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"exec\": executable file not found in $PATH"` It seemingly cannot find `exec`.

Comment: can you post your Dockerfile?

Comment: posted a reproducible example, and also kinda found a solution, by simply removing everything from an array.